# Refresh UITableView with iCloud changes

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have an app where I have intergrated core data with iCloud. I have the following notifications in my view controller.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:) name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification object:coreDataController.psc];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coreDataController.psc];
```

The view controller contains a `UITableView` that is loaded with core data using `NSFetchedResultsController`. I am unsure  what to put in the following method (called by the notifications above) to refresh the table. I have tried reloading the table, and refetching the data but to no avail. I know that the iCloud is doing its job because if I completely reload the viewcontroller the changed data shows.

```
- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSLog(@"Underlying data changed ... refreshing!");

    //_fetchedResultsController=nil;
    //[self fetchedResultsController];

    [theTableView reloadData];


}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually refreshing your data source? Or just reloading the table?

Comment: Well I've tried calling the `NSFetchResultsController` delegate methods to re-fetch the data, (the bit commented out) but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to fetch another set of data, or are you looking to see changes to the same results set? If the former, tear it down and rebuild with a new predicate, fetch, etc. And perform fetch.

If the latter, you need to merge your changes in with your moc. When you register for notifications, set it up like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(documentContentsImportedChanges:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator];


- (void) documentContentsImportedChanges:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // Received updates from iCloud
    [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it was the latter.

Comment: 5 Thumbs Up! Awesome answer, and a fantastic question. Worked for me, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jason's answer. However, you should make sure you perform updates in the correct thread.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:)
                   name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                 object:_persistentStoreCoordinator];

- (void)persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:(NSNotification*)note
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;
    [moc performBlock:^{
        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];

    }];
}
```

This method of updating your MOC makes sure its done in the same thread as the context so you don't have any crashes ;)